# Markdown is not working in the Bot Framework Twilio channel

Tags: sms, twilio, botframework

I am trying to create a simple bot that sends images and hyperlinks by SMS using Twilio (trial account).

I do get the reply from the bot , but none of the markdown is working, even simple markdown elements like **text** or [bing](http://bing.com)

Sample code I am using to send the message through Twilio SMS channel:

```
 public async Task<Message> Post([FromBody]Message message)
        {
            if(message.Text == "Hello")
            {

                string messageText = "![Sample Image](http://aka.ms/Fo983c)";
                return message.CreateReplyMessage(messageText);
            }
```

Am I missing something? The emulator displays the image and other markdown properly, but when I test using my android phone and text the Twilio number to connect to the bot, it delivers raw HTML and not the rich content.

Comment: SMS is just plain text. However the receiving SMS client chooses to parse and display a message is entirely up to it, and I know of no SMS client that supports markdown or HTML. There's nothing you can include in a text message to force an arbitrary client to render a message in any other way than it chooses. Most clients will linkify URLs, email address, phone numbers, etc., if they are found in the message body, but that's about it for special formatting.

Comment: Thank you. My intent is to send links, images and text in the reply to the phone. What is the best way to do this ? The sms channel is not meant for this then ?

Comment: If you want the actual images in the messages, you're talking about MMS, not SMS. Also, if you format the URLs correctly, they will most likely be made into links automatically by the receiving app.

Comment: hi Mike, How do I send or configure MMS messages using the bot framework ? Thank you

Comment: No clue. I got here by the [sms] tag. I've never used the Bot Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here. As pointed our earlier SMS is text only, so markdown or any other formatting will not work.

I just tried sending a message from a bot, and while I get the image correctly on the emulator or webchat, on SMS I only get the URL of the image (i.e. http://aka.ms/Fo983c).

According to [the documentation](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-content/#markdown-paragraphs), this is the expected behavior as it states:

> Not all channels can represent all markdown fields. As appropriate
>   channels will fallback to a reasonable approximation, for example,
>   bold will be represented in text messaging as *bold*

So I guess for images, it will always fallback to the URL of the image.

As for sending MMS, it appears right now the botframework doesn't support it. To be clear, Twilio itself does support MMS for US and Canada, but it seems Microsoft's implementation didn't take advantage of that right now.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: hi Marcos,
i am using the microsoft bot framework code. I did see the above code documentation on twilio site, but my code is using C# and the botframework, just using the twilio as the SMS channel.
 
What I want to do is send MMS messages using the bot framework, but not sure how to do this.  @Mike How do I send MMS messages using the bot frame work or configure it for MMS ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I did this when I was first trying out the framework.  Sorry but I don't have that code anymore however I don't recall having to do anything special.  I simply sent a picture from my phone to my twilio number and then in the message properties for the message received by the bot there was an attachment field with a URL pointing to the image sent from my phone.  Then I used a regular web request to pull down the image.

The details for the attachment objects and content url fields [are outlined here](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-content/#navtitle).

Because there's no way to emulate the SMS channel you'll have to publish the code live to be able to test it out.

Have fun!

Comment: hi Roland how do I send a different image back to the phone ? through an attachment as well ? does it not need to be a MMS message to send rich content?

Comment: You won't need to do anything special with the framework to do this.  This is simply a Twilio call.  You would make a call to the Twilio REST API passing in an image in whichever parameter is called for from the documentation and Twilio will handle sending it to the phone.